# Numbering pages (ex. PAGE ONE)

Tags: word-choice, counters, numbers

Although it might seem a tad pointless, I am trying to number pages in a document without using Arabic numerals (0, 1, 2 etc.). I would like the reading to similar to "PAGE ONE" or "FIRST PAGE." I'm doing this for graphic design purposes, and although I have come up with some information, I'm having a bit of a hard time piecing it all together.

Should I be using **枚** and **ページ** combined with **一つ**? Maybe one or the other? What I have come up with so far is  **初めにページ**, but I have the feeling that isn't quite right since I kind of duct taped it together.

Comment: Are you just numbering the pages of the book?

Comment: They are pages in a graphic design document/pitch package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the purpose is purely visual, you could use 一頁, 二頁, and so on, where 頁 is the kanji used for ページ, and the reading remains いちぺーじ、にぺーじ.

For more information, you can try searching for ノンブル, which is the term used for the concept of page numbering, as described [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB), but there seems to be very little about using numbering that doesn't involve Arabic numerals.

Comment: I've never heard 一頁 as 「いち・ページ」, only as 「いっページ」.

Comment: So then if I use 一頁, will it seem like I am saying "one page" as in, the amount of pages, rather than something closer to first page?

Comment: @HatakeKazuko: No. 一頁 is "page 1”, regardless of whether you write it all in kanji, as 1ページ, or even as "p. 1”. It's not an amount.

Comment: @istrasci: There could be regional differences, but I generally hear いちベージ for the page number, and いっページ for the quantity (i.e. "Keep your summary down to just one page.”

Comment: @Philippe Thanks so much, a simple response but exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have found that the pages in books/documents are numbered the same way English books or documents are numbered, the Arabic number is sufficient.  If you have a prologue, or a preliminary section with an introduction, you can use the lower case roman numerals.

If you're looking for something more formal where you physically write "Page 1, Page 2, ..." on the pages, then 「１頁、２頁、...」should be fine.  In this second method you could use Kanji just fine as well: 「一頁、二頁、...」